# Add firefox as device when running flutter web

Tags: flutter, flutter-web, flutter-web-browser

I want to add Firefox as my default browser when running flutter for web (chrome has errors with some packages). I've done this before on Ubuntu 20.4 but I've switched to arch and I can't remember how I've done it.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can run the project with `web-server` as the device :

`flutter run -d web-server`

Then you can open the url where `lib/main.dart` is served (it is shown on console), from the browser of your choice (e.g Firefox).

Comment: Thanks. Before on Ubuntu I could run directly on firefox (only pressing `F5` ) but this is also a pretty good alternative!